# How to setup Google Pay Console to integrate Android application for Google pay API

Tags: android, google-pay

As in Test environment I am getting the response from google, with test example token, but in production environment I am getting error :- `You have not registered to use this API`.
I have gone through the troubleshoot document as well [Troubleshoot google doc](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting), there it is mentioned

> You haven't completed the process to register your app for the Google Pay API. Review Request production access for more information.

But in google pay console I am not getting the option for requesting production access, rather I am getting the view for which I have attached a image Google pay dashboard.

[image: Google pay dashboard]

I am trying to reach out Google pay support for this but no response yet. I am supposing I am missing something in google pay console or in integration setup, can anyone help me out with this, will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you click on **Create an integration**?

When I visit the Google Pay Business Console (https://pay.google.com/business/console/payment/YOUR_MERCHANT_ID), I get the following:

[image: android integration text]

I get this because I don't have a Google Play developer account attached to my email address, but I believe that if you've got a Google Play developer account, that *should* allow you choose from a list of your Android apps.

What do you see if you click on **Google Pay API** on the left hand menu?